# How to center my content's section on CSS?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to make an aquarium website, but I can't center my text and button in CSS.

Desired result:
[image: I want the website to look like this]

Result:
[image: But mine look like this]

And this my code:

```css
* {
  color: white;
}

.banner {
  background: #000;
}

.banner-inner {
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  gap: 5rem;
}

.banner-card1 {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(./img/project2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.banner-card2 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(./img/project3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div class="container banner-container">
    <div class="banner-inner">
      <div class="banner-card1">
        <h3>AQUARIUM DESIGN</h3>
        <a href="aquarium-design.html" class="btn"> Checkout</a>
      </div>
      <div class="banner-card2">
        <h3>AQUARIUM STUFF</h3>
        <a href="aquarium-stuff.html" class="btn"> Checkout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these flex styles to `.banner-card1` and `.banner-card2`:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
}

.banner {
  background: #000;
}

.banner-inner {
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  gap: 5rem;
}

.banner-card1 {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(./img/project2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.banner-card2 {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(./img/project3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div class="container banner-container">
    <div class="banner-inner">
      <div class="banner-card1">
        <h3>AQUARIUM DESIGN</h3>
        <a href="aquarium-design.html" class="btn"> Checkout</a>
      </div>
      <div class="banner-card2">
        <h3>AQUARIUM STUFF</h3>
        <a href="aquarium-stuff.html" class="btn"> Checkout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```